# How to prevent apt upgrade from downgrading my kernel?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, apt, upgrade

I needed to manually install (through `apt`) a specific kernel version that supports newer USB-C features for USB development -- specifically version `linux-image-4.18.0-25-generic` in the Ubuntu apt repos.

Now whenever I try to perform an `apt upgrade`, it wants to install an older kernel version:

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fwupd-signed libxmlb1 linux-headers-4.15.0-73 linux-headers-4.15.0-73-generic linux-image-4.15.0-73-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-73-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-73-generic
< ... snip ... >
```

So I tried to keep back my current kernel using `apt-mark hold` as follows:

```
$ sudo apt-mark hold linux-headers-4.18.0-25-generic linux-headers-4.18.0-25 linux-image-4.18.0-25-generic linux-modules-4.18.0-25-generic linux-modules-extra-4.18.0-25-generic
linux-headers-4.18.0-25-generic set on hold.
linux-headers-4.18.0-25 set on hold.
linux-image-4.18.0-25-generic set on hold.
linux-modules-4.18.0-25-generic set on hold.
linux-modules-extra-4.18.0-25-generic set on hold.
```

But when I run `apt upgrade`, it is still trying to fetch the older kernel and prints the exact same confirmation prompt as above.

How do I keep my current (newer) kernel version after an `apt upgrade`?

Comment: Please show in the question how APT is telling you that it is intending to remove the 4.18.0 kernel package .

Comment: @JdeBP it isn't saying it will remove it, which isn't my first concern anyway. my experience with apt is that when it installs a new kernel, it updates the bootloader configuration to load that new kernel. I don't want it to do that, regardless if it keeps or removes the kernel I'm currently using.

Comment: The default setup should choose the latest kernel by default — not the most recently-installed kernel, but the one with the highest version number; so your 4.18 should stay the default if a 4.15 is installed alongside it.

Comment: Asking you to show in the question how APT is telling you that you wouldn't be able to bootstrap the 4.18.0 kernel was going to be my next subtle nudge.  (-:

Comment: So there isn't a feature or standard procedure to do what I think you guys understand I'm trying to do? Is `apt-mark hold` the correct utility? I should just let apt do whatever it's going to do (which none of us are entirely certain what that will be) and hope to clean up any mess it may make afterwards? Can we agree the resulting state of the system is a little ambiguous given this message?

Comment: Why would it fetch an older kernel if it has no intent on using it?

Comment: I've no idea why you think that we're uncertain of what I'm subtly nudging you about.  I'm confident that M. Kitt has also installed multiple kernel packages with APT, as I have.

Comment: @JdeBP because I can't figure out why'd you prefer subtlety for a rather explicit question unless you didn't have confidence to give anything more than vague information. So anyway, if you can't or simply refuse to concretely tell me what will happen by this upgrade (or if there is another method I can use to protect my current kernel configuration (or why it is fetching this old kernel at all in the first place if it doesn't intend to use it)), I'll just do it and see what happens. Not trying to be difficult, but it feels like pulling teeth to get concrete info from you

Comment: @StephenKitt thanks for the info, that makes sense. I'll have to verify and report back

Comment: The concrete information is _right in front of your nose_.  I was trying with gentle prodding to get you to read it and think about it.

Comment: I was alerted by this `apt` behavior too just recently.

I'm currently running 5.3 kernel from the "proposed" Ubuntu repository and today apt wanted to install and configure some 4.15.

The apt did install the 4.15.x but I can confirm what @StephenKitt said, that the setup will use the **latest** version and not the most recently installed one. So all is good after the kernel update and I'm still on 5.3.0 even after the confusing messages from apt.